# Python, for loop that prints 16 charracters at a time

Tags: python

I am trying to loop through a string and print out every sixteen characters. The string also ends with a semicolon. This is what I have currently but I am looking for something that prints like this `ARI:03,21-04,19;` This is instead what I am getting

```
i = 0
for word in SIGNS:
    print(word[:i], end='')
    i += 16
```

The output is

```
R
I
:
0
3
,
2
1
-
0
4 
,
1
9
;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link to know more about asking questions here as your question isn't very descriptive or doesn't include samples of your efforts or examples with proper Formatting.

Comment: Format code as code please.

Comment: What does the data in `SIGNS` look like?

Comment: It is a very long string which I am trying to print out 16 characters at a time.'ARI:03,21-04,19;TAU:04,20-05,20;GEM:05,21-06,21;CAN:06,22-07,22;' + \
        'LEO:07,23-08,22;VIR:08,23-09,22;LIB:09,23-10,23;SCO:10,24-11,20;' + \
        'SAG:11,21-12,21;CAP:12,22-01,20;AQU:01,21-02,21;PIS:02,22-03,20;'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should print 16 characters at a time:

```
i = 0
#for word in SIGNS:
for i in range(0, len(SIGNS), 16):
    print(SIGNS[i:i+16])
```

Don't use `for word in SIGNS:` as it iterates through the string in `SIGNS` **character-by-character**, which is what messed you up.

Comment: You're welcome. Would you have preferred it, I mentioned it before I changed it?

Comment: @ViG On Stack Overflow, pointing out mistakes in comments or suggesting edits are **both appropriate** actions. So you can choose whatever you like to do.

Comment: @ViG Another courteous reminder: Be cautious when suggesting (or applying, after you have 2k reputation) non-trivial answers. You should only fix trivial mistakes like obvious typos. If the mistake is non-trivial, leave a comment to the author.

Comment: @iBug you can use `range(0, len(SIGNS), 16)` instead of the `while` loop

Comment: @AndreyF Great. Suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Is there is a chance you want to split your data? It looks like the format of your data is separated by `;`. In that case you can use:

```
data_as_list =  SIGNS.split(';')
for record in data_as_list:
   print(record)
```